# Understanding Calling limit of entry-point in Tezos smart-contract until the previous request to the contract is confirmed (block backed)

Tags: tezos-client, ligo, conseiljs

Image if I have a smart contract with entry-point `increment()` that increments a counter.

So if I call this entry-point for the first time and we know that it takes almost 1 minute for the operation to be confirmed and baked.

and all sub-sequent request fails until the block is confirmed.

So does this set a limit on me to call this function, eg I can only call increment the counter by 60 in 1 hour..?

I need help to make sure that my understanding is right or not and also if there is any way I can achieve a greater limit!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you send a transaction that calls the increment entry point of the contract. For that to happen, the transaction will have to be included in a block and, as you mention, blocks come about every minute. However, a single block could contain many such transactions and, as a result, the counter could be incremented by more than one during the execution of a block.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but when I try to call the increment method again even before the block is confirmed, my request simply fails.
I am using conseiljs to do so.
Do you have any idea what I may be doing wrong?.

Comment: The transactions that you produce include a counter attached to the account at the source of the transaction. You need to increment this counter for the second transaction. If you need help with this you should create a separate, conseiljs specific, question.